# Can multiple records be added one at a time using await _db.SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working on a ASP.Net Razor Page app.  On one page when a user enters a year, and event handler determines the date of the first Sunday in the year and displays the date in a text box. The On Post handler saves the date to the database, then adds seven days to the First Sunday Date to determine the next Sunday Date. When the OnPost tries to save next Sunday Date the program crashes.  Is it possible to save multiple records one at a time using my code?  Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

```
//*****cshtml.cs*****
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using PublicTalkSchedule.Data;
using PublicTalkSchedule.Models;
using Document = System.Reflection.Metadata.Document;

namespace PublicTalkSchedule.Pages.TalksIncoming
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        // ***** success message - displays message from create, edit or delete page *****
        [TempData]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public string lblMessage { get; set; }
        public DateTime currentDate { get; set; }
        public int weekDay { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Year field is required... ")]
        public string txtYear { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Sunday Date field is required... ")]
        public string txtSunday { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public ScheduleIn scheduleIn { get; set; }


        // OnGet
        public IActionResult OnGet(DateTime sunDate, string newYear)
        {
            //determine if sunDate is a valid Sunday date for the selected year.  if valid, run code. if blank
            //(MinValue equals 01/01/0001 and indicates a blank textbox), skip code. the initialize schedule page appears
            if (sunDate != DateTime.MinValue)   
            {
                txtYear = newYear;

                var strSunday = sunDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                txtSunday = strSunday;
            }

            txtYear = newYear;

            return Page();
        }



        // OnPost
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var newYear = Request.Form["txtYear"];      //get the first Sunday from the page
            DateTime yearEndMarker = Convert.ToDateTime("12/25/" + newYear);   

            var newSunday = Request.Form["txtSunday"];        //get the first Sunday from the page
            DateTime currentSunday = Convert.ToDateTime(newSunday);   //convert String to DateTime

            scheduleIn.DOT = currentSunday;

           
            do
            {
                _db.ScheduleIn.Add(scheduleIn);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

                currentSunday = currentSunday.AddDays(7);
                scheduleIn.DOT = currentSunday;

            } while (currentSunday.Date <= yearEndMarker.Date);


            return RedirectToPage("Index");                         //return to Index page
        }



        //On Post - Initialize Year  
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostInitializeYear()
        {
            var newYear = Request.Form["txtYear"];      //get the selected year

            //add newYear to jan. 1, then convert to datetime. 
            currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/" + newYear);
            weekDay = Convert.ToInt32(currentDate.DayOfWeek);

            //determine he first Sunday in the year.  increase sunDate by 1 until weekDay equals 0 )
            do
            {
                currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
                weekDay = Convert.ToInt32(currentDate.DayOfWeek);
            }
            while (weekDay != 0);
                       
            return RedirectToPage("Create", new { sunDate = currentDate, newYear = newYear });
        }   
    }
}


//*****cshtml
@page
@model PublicTalkSchedule.Pages.TalksIncoming.CreateModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!-- *************** code used to display success message *************** -->
@if (Model.Message != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aira-label="close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        @Model.Message
    </div>
}


<!-- ****************************** Create (initilize) Incoming New Year Schedule Banner ****************************** -->
<br />
<h4 class="text-info"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Initialize New Calendar Year for Incoming Talk Schedule</h4>
<br />

<form method="post">

    <div class="border backgroundwhite">

        <!-- setup border, texbox (for new calendar year) and submit button-->
        <div style="height:110px;" class="container border border-secondary">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px">
                        <div class="col-1"></div>
                        <!-- textbox NewYear-->
                        <div class="col-4 text-right">
                            <h4 id="lblYear" class="text-info pl-1 pt-1 pb-1">Enter New Year:</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="txtYear" runat="server" id="txtYear"
                                   class="text-black pl-1 pt-1 pb-1" style="width:90px; text-align:center" />
                        </div>
                        <span asp-validation-for="txtYear" class="text-danger"></span>

                        <div class="col-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-2 text-right">
                            <!-- submit button -->
                            <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="InitializeYear" runat="server"
                                    class="form-control btn btn-primary">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br />

                <!-- *************** if tstYear is null, then hide txtSunday and txtLabel ***************-->
                <!-- display first sunday date for new calendar year with confirm button -->
                @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.txtYear))
                {
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px">
                            <div class="col-2"></div>
                            <!--txtSunay-->
                            <div class="col-11 offset-2" style="padding-bottom:10px" text-align:center>
                                <input type="text" asp-for="txtSunday" runat="server" id="txtSunday"
                                       class="text-black pl-1 pt-1 pb-1" style="width:100px" ; text-align:center />
                                <h10 id="lblSunday" class="text-info pl-1 pt-5 pb-1">is the FIRST Sunday the year. If this is correct, click Create</h10>
                            </div>

                            <!--lblSunday-->
                            @*<div class="col-8">
                                <h10 id="lblSunday" class="text-info pl-1 pt-5 pb-1">is the FIRST Sunday the year. If this is correct, click Continue</h10>
                            </div>*@
                        </div>

                    </div>
                }
                <!-- ************************* LAST LINE OF HIDEN IV SECTION ***************-->

            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <!-- add buttons-->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-5 offset-3">
                <partial name="_CreateAndBackToListButton" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>

@section Scripts{
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, the code did not recognize that every new date in the loop should be viewed as a new record to be inserted into the database.  The first three lines in the Do While statement resolved the problem.

```
// OnPost
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var newYear = Request.Form["txtYear"];                              
    DateTime yearEndMarker = Convert.ToDateTime("12/31/"                                                         
        + newYear);

    var newSunday = Request.Form["txtSunday"];                          
    DateTime currentSunday = 
                          Convert.ToDateTime(newSunday);             

    do
    {
       //the next three lines makes each iteration      
       //appear as a new record to be saved 
       scheduleIn = new ScheduleIn()
       {
           DOT = currentSunday
       };

         _db.ScheduleIn.Add(scheduleIn);
         await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

         currentSunday = currentSunday.AddDays(7);

   } while (currentSunday.Date <=  
                               yearEndMarker.Date);

     Message = "The year " + newYear + " has been 
                successfully initialized";

     return RedirectToPage("Index");                         
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to pure entity framework, then you can't achieve that. As each entity framework call will be translated to a sql statement. So it will be multiple calls.

Depends on your usage scenario, you could:

1. Create a stored procedure and add your schedule there. It will be in
   one call and more efficient then entity framework. You just call it
   from entity framework
2. Raw SQL Queries. Similar to sp, but you create sql statement in c#. There is a danger of sql injection, but as long as you
   parameterize your sql correctly, no problem.

Saying that, if your page is quick enough, you may not bother and stick to EF.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Can you provide an example of a SQL query that I can use.  I assume the query can be placed in the OnPost , correct?